# Can we use a sub domain for our aws ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain

I have bought a domain from nexcess.net (example.com) on which my website is hosted, now I have to create a secondary domain (one.etc.example.com) from the nexcess site and point it to my ec2 instance.
Is it possible using nexcess?
Can anyone guide me how?

Comment: Yes you can, please check https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-subdomain-route-53/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps would be:

- Create an **Elastic IP address** and associate it with the EC2 instance (this gives it a static IP address)
- Create an `A` record in your domain to point the desired domain name

You can create the `A` record where ever your domain is managed, whether it is using Amazon Route 53 or your own DNS provider.